# Drawing a simple grid in canvas?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, grid, awt

I've written Conway's Game Of Life in Java and I want to display it in a browser. I wanted to learn some Canvas, so what is the preferred way to draw a 2D grid and filling each cell in with a color? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will make a grid. It's useful I think for being able to position or determine the coordinates of an element or something, and several other possible handy use cases as well.

```
var grid = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < canvasWidth || i < canvasHeight; i += 100) { // 100 represents the width in pixels between each line of the grid
        // draw horizontal lines
        ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(i, canvasHeight);
        // draw vertical lines
        ctx.moveTo(0, i);
        ctx.lineTo(canvasWidth, i);
    }
    ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(200, 0%, 20%, 0.8)';
        ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
};

// Call the function
grid()
```

Hope this helps, and is what you're trying to do too. :)

edit: If you are looking to fill each grid square with a different color, then this function will not work, or could at least be used in combination with another function which creates and fills the squares in a similar way to the function above but cutting the width and height off based on the dimensions of the canvas width and height.